# Is this space Hausdorff and are these two spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \  | \ x^2 + y^2 = 1  \}$. We define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S^1$ such that $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ if and only if $y = y'$.
>   Now we study the following quotient space:
>   $X :=S^1 / \sim$ with the quotient topology.

My questions:

Is $X$ a Hausdorff space?

Are $[\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{4}]$ and $X$ homeomorphic?

My thoughts so far:

If I think about the space $X$ I see the half unit circle from $X =  \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \  | \ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \wedge x \geq 0  \}$. Is this a correct way to think about the quotient space? Cause it could also be the same but with $x \leq 0$.. But if this is correct we notice that $X \subset S^1 \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ and since $\mathbb{R}^2 $ is Hausdorff we know that $X$ is hausdorff.

Now that we know $X$ is Hausdorff and since $[\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{4}]$ is compact we know that if we have a continuous function $f: [\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{4}]\rightarrow X $ then $f$ is a homeomorphism. But do I still need to define $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by $[1/4,1/4]$? Unless you mean something different, this is just a one-point set $\{1/4\}$, which certainly couldn't be homeomorphic to any nontrivial space.

Comment: Should be $[-1/4,1/4]$.

Comment: Yes, you must define $f$. I suggest that the easiest way is first to write down a homeomorphism from $S^1/\!\!\sim$ onto $[-1,1]$, because there’s a really simple one, and then compose this with a homeomorphism of $[-1,1]$ onto $\left[-\frac14,\frac14\right]$, something that can again be very simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, when you define $X$ as a set, I think you mean $\wedge x\geq 0$, not $\vee x\geq 0$. Next, you have to show that the subspace topology on $X$ is equivalent to the quotient topology on $S^1/\sim$ . Finally, you should explicitly state $f$ (remember the formula for a circle?), anr remember that $f$ must also be bijective.